# Why is the not equal to "<>" sign in excel VBA displays a compile error

Tags: excel, vba, operators

I do not know why I get an error when using the "<>" sign in excel-VBA.

I want that whenever cell G4 has a value of "R", cell G8 should not have a blank value. If G8 has a blank value it will display an error message.
Otherwise if G4 is not R, it should run completely.

```
On Error GoTo ErrrHndlr:

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G4").Value = "R" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G8").Value <> ""

Else

Range("C4:C9").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True

ErrrHndlr:
MsgBox "Cell G8 cannot be blank if G4 has letter R"

End If

End Sub
```

Using the "<>" value creates a "Compile: Error"

Comment: You need another `If...Then`.

Comment: can you show me where? i really dont get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rearrange your code like that

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G4").Value = "R" Then

    If Len(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G8").Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cell G8 cannot be blank if G4 has letter R"
    End If

Else

    Range("C4:C9").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True

End If
```